# Why Number(" ") is equal 0

Tags: javascript

I'm using the Number js object to get a number from a string.
For example:

```
Number("123") -> 123
Number(":") -> NaN
```

but when I'm trying `Number(" ")` the result is `0`
and with `parseFloat(" ")` the result is `Nan`
that's unclear to me why space output is a 0 with Number and NaN with parseFloat

Comment: Because javascript is weird!? And it was defined that way.

Comment: As with most of this type of question: [Because the spec says so](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-stringnumericvalue)

Comment: it's like `Number("")` but after using `trim()`

Comment: As a guess I’d say that the function does its best to coerce the input into a number. It probably trims the input so space becomes an empty string, which can be coerced to a false value, which can be coerced into zero

Comment: Because the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number-constructor-number-value) says so.